# Cache Channel Service is not able to send cache invalidation messages

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, configuration, cache-channel-service

Cache Channel Service is not able to send cache invalidation messages

Are all users affected, if NO provide at least one user ID:
Yes, all users using Tridion functionality. All dynamic content dependent on this feature in  Tridion
 Error message/degraded performance:

> 2016-10-24 10:33:29,314 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache
>   event because communication queue size 2048 was exceeded ([CacheEvent
>   eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta
>   key=52:304113] was dropped)

Action that led to error:
change a dynamic component in staging and republish

Business impact:
Medium. Pending on which new content can't be republished/updated

Examples:
There is a problem on Tridion 2013 staging where Cache Channel Service is not able to send cache invalidation messages. This means that if we change a dynamic component in staging and republish, the changes won't propagate.

> "2016-10-24 10:33:29,314 ERROR CacheChannel - Did not process cache
>   event because communication queue size 2048 was exceeded ([CacheEvent
>   eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta
>   key=52:304113] was dropped)."

Comment: could you please let us know why this issue is happening and how to resolve the issue

Comment: we increased queue size in cd-storage.xml but no luck

Comment: Might I suggest that you edit your question so that it's not so obviously a copy-paste of something in a support ticket system? So firstly - you need to actually ask a question. I see that the message is about exceeding the communication queue size; can you elaborate on how your system is arranged and what configuration values you have?